# How do I use col.names and colClasses together in `data.table::fread`?

Tags: r, csv, data.table

As an simple example, I write `cars` out without column names.

```r
data.table::fwrite(cars, "cars.csv", col.names = FALSE)
```

and then I try to read them in with column names and by specifying the type of column `a`

```r
data.table::fread("cars.csv", col.names = c("a","b"),
                  colClasses = list(a = "numeric"))
```

and I get this error

> Error in data.table::fread("cars.csv", col.names = c("a", "b"),
>   colClasses = list(a = "numeric")) :    Column name 'numeric' in
>   colClasses[[1]] not found

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possible solution is to use the index of the column and not the name.

```
data.table::fread("cars.csv", col.names = c("a","b"), colClasses = list(numeric = 1))
```

Comment: Seems to be the only way but is terrible from a user perspective.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that `data.table` process the `colClasses` argument before `col.names`. Therefore, except for the workaround provided by the other answer, there are two alternative ways:

```
# option1: A character vector of classes
fread("cars.csv", colClasses = c(V1 = "numeric"), col.names = c("a","b"))

# option2: Or a named list of vectors of column names or numbers
fread("cars.csv", colClasses = list(numeric = "V1"), col.names = c("a","b"))
```

here, `V1` is the auto-dectected name of the first colomn.

Comment: This solution works only for data without col.names, while the "workaround" works also for data with colnames. I don't see the improvement of "V1" over using 1 as in both cases you need to know the position of the column.

Comment: @kath, the major point I want to make is to explain why this kind of error happens. data.table parse the colClasses argument first to read the data and set the col.names later. Once we know why, we know how to do workaround. The two alternative ways are minor points.  I agree that your answer is more elegant. "V1" is auto-dectacted. If the data has header, we can just replace "V1" with the corresponding value in header.